# How do I add 3 times loop in HTML5/CSS3/JS Banner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a banner in html5. its working fine one time. But I need to add 3 times loop in this banner. Can anyone help me?

## My Code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="slide1">
        <div id="Img1"><img src="images/slide_image_1.jpg"></div>
        <div id="tnumbAnimation"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2"></div>
    <div id="copy1">With our Personal Loan,<br>your only summer challenge<br>is reading 800 hotel reviews. </div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="copy2">Now with AED 500 <br>airline voucher and more</div>
    <div id="cta"><a href="#">Find out more</a></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I have used JavaScript to load images for animation.


thumb_img_url=thumb_img_url + '<div id="Img'+i+'"><img src="images/slide_image_'+j+'.jpg"></div>';
   document.getElementById("tnumbAnimation").innerHTML=thumb_img_url;

Comment: @engr.Kamal You should edit your question with the code instead of commenting

Answer (score 0):

Without the specific JavaScript code you use to implement the animation, it's difficult to answer this question, but based on the fact that you're using variables `i` and `j`, I guess you're using an iteration loop like `for()` or `while()`. If this is the case, if you want it to loop three times you could just set another variable that  tracks how many times it's already completed, and then resets your `i` and/or `j` variables as needed until it has executed three times.

Comment: No. I used i & j to load all necessary images for animation. I want to give loop for hole content inside <div id="container">.